# searchclear button location is displaced

Tags: jquery, css

I have livesearch script it works good. but as you see this image below searchclear button is displaced.
I have TWO js script into my page so I loaded two CDN. that cause this displaced happen I think.
Could someone teach me what is wrong my code please?

here is my whole code
https://jsfiddle.net/blueink/hq86Lxs2/3/

Here is my livesearch section

```
    <div class="btn-group">
        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="input 1" class="search form-control" size="3000"
               onkeypress="return event.keyCode!=13"/>
      <span class="searchclear glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
    </div>

    <ul class="list-group result"></ul>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to use an input group you need to use the `input-group-append` class.

See [the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/) for examples.

```
<div id="searchComponent-1">

<div class="btn-group">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="input 1" class="search form-control" size="3000"
           onkeypress="return event.keyCode!=13"/>
  <div class=input-group-append>
    <span class="searchclear glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
  </div>
</div>

<ul class="list-group result"></ul>
```

Comment: Dear @John Thank you for helping me. I tried your code but displace is not fixed and clear funtion became off...

Comment: Dear @John Sorry my bad! your code was perfect! THANK you so much for helping me!